# How to get Consumer Price Index(CPI) in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, web-scraping, xpath, google-query-language, google-finance

Need to get [Australia Consumer Price Index(CPI)](https://au.investing.com/economic-calendar/cpi-1011) and update all the prices in my sheet every quarter based on it.

Tried to do that using `GoogleFinance`.

[Found that its possible](https://www.google.co.uk/googlefinance/disclaimer/) to use exchange like **ASX** for that and indexes from the [list](https://www.asx.com.au/asx/statistics/indexInfo.do). But CPI index is not represented there.

Is there any way to get Australia CPI index in Google Sheets or calculate it based on other indexes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=QUERY(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(IMPORTXML(
 "https://au.investing.com/economic-calendar/cpi-1011", "//*"), 1500, 5), 
 "select Col4 where Col3 ='Actual' limit 1", 0)
```

[image: 0]